# Why Does Pagination Appear Outside HTML Tag Wrapper?

Tags: pagination

This has bugged me for a while and I'd really like to know what the heck is going on. Here's my template:

```
<header>
    {!-- Pre-Pagination Header Content --}

{exp:channel:entries
    channel='mychannel'
    limit='10'
    disable='member_data'
    paginate='both'
}
    {if count == 1}
        {paginate}
            {pagination_links}
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {previous_page}
                        <li class="prev"><a href="{pagination_url}">&laquo;</a></li>
                    {/previous_page}
                    <span class="numbers">
                        {page}
                            <li{if current_page} class="here"{/if}>{if current_page == ''}<a href="{pagination_url}">{/if}{pagination_page_number}{if current_page == ''}</a>{/if}</li>
                        {/page}
                    </span><!--/.numbers-->
                    {next_page}
                        <li class="next"><a href="{pagination_url}">&raquo;</a></li>
                    {/next_page}
                </ul><!--/.pagination-->
            {/pagination_links}
        {/paginate}
    </header>

    <div class="listing">
    {/if}

    {!-- Listing Item Content --}

    {if count == total_results}
        </div><!--/.listing-->

        <footer>
            {paginate}
                {pagination_links}
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        {previous_page}
                            <li class="prev"><a href="{pagination_url}">&laquo;</a></li>
                        {/previous_page}
                        <span class="numbers">
                            {page}
                                <li{if current_page} class="here"{/if}>{if current_page == ''}<a href="{pagination_url}">{/if}{pagination_page_number}{if current_page == ''}</a>{/if}</li>
                            {/page}
                        </span><!--/.numbers-->
                        {next_page}
                            <li class="next"><a href="{pagination_url}">&raquo;</a></li>
                        {/next_page}
                    </ul><!--/.pagination-->
                {/pagination_links}
            {/paginate}
        </footer>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The pagination inside the header displays fine, but in the footer, the pagination `<ul>` displays *after* the `<footer>` tag it's wrapped in.

Why? Why does ExpressionEngine do that? Does it have to do with the `paginate` parameter? Is there a way to fix it besides buying AB Pagination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pagination will display at the top, bottom or top and bottom of the channel entries tag (depending on what you set in the `paginate=""` parameter). It doesn't matter where you place `{paginate}` it in the template code itself.

Either use a pagination addon (like AB Pagination) or use Stash.

Mark Croxton has an example of how he moves his pagination to where he wants using Stash.
https://gist.github.com/croxton/1206694

Comment: Because EE *never* gets into trouble when it doesn't let the developer choose where to put code. ;)

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing this is more to do with a problem with your HTML (such as a tag that hasn't been closed or has been incorrectly nested) or, more likely, your CSS and quite possibly related to floated or absolutely position elements.